# How to add more values in DataGrid Column in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

i placed 3 columns in data grid.colname as textbox,coldesc as textbox,coltype as dropdownlist.whenever user selects coltype as radio in dropdown then i need to display another column option in that first i need to display one textbox behind one + button whenever click on + another textbox need to display like that user enters the data in textboxes.

how to display the another column in grid whenever user slects radio type in dropdown and how to take the data from users in option column of datagrid.

please tell me any samples for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use EditItemTemplate with controls to input data and switch to edit mode on dropdown's SelectedIndexChanged event. IAC you can't add new column to whole GridView but can emulate it with a custom layout in EditItemTemplate fields.